# Choice with similar sequences

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have this xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://HIDDEN/Queues"
    xmlns="http://HIDDEN/Queues">

    <xs:complexType name="Queue">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element fixed="1" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element fixed="a" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element fixed="2" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element fixed="b" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The goal is that an element with the type Queue should be able to look like this:

```
<Queue>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>a</name>
</Queue>
```

but as soon as either id or name do not match togehter (e.g id=2 name=a) it should fail.

The part im confused abt is this error:

"http://HIDDEN/Queues":id and "http://HIDDEN/Queues":id (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

I mean i see what its referencing to but those are elements that cant exist at the same time so idk how to fix that.
One idea i had was to jus make id and name as attributes but my boss said i cant do that (dont ask me why).

Do any of you know any other approaches?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using XSD 1.1?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky im currently using XSD 2.0

Comment: The XSD schema language has two versions, 1.0 and 1.1. I am not sure what you refer to with XSD 2.0, whether that is the version of the tool you use. But Yitzhak's question is about the XSD version you use or whether you can use XSD version 1.1 where perhaps you could use assertions, I suppose.

Comment: There are only two XSD standards: 1.0 and 1.1. If you are using XSD 1.1, it has an **assert** statement to express Business Rules - exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on XSD 1.1 that is using an **assert** statement to enforce correct combinations of *id* and *name* values.

**Input XML**

```
<Queue xmlns="http://HIDDEN/Queues">
    <id>1</id>
    <name>a</name>
</Queue>
```

**XSD 1.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://HIDDEN/Queues"
           xmlns="http://HIDDEN/Queues"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="Queue">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="id"/>
                <xs:element ref="name"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="string-join((xs:string(id), name), '~') = ('1~a', '2~b')"
                       xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Rule #: 20-70</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation>Combination of id and name values shall be correct</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:assert>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```